# How to specify two sources, one process operator and one sink operator in flink application

Tags: apache-flink

I am using flink 1.3, I have defined two stream sources that will emit out same events to be processed by subsequent operators(my defined process operator and sink operator)

But it looks that in the source-process-pink pipeline, I could only specify one source, I would ask how to specify two or more sources and do the same process and sink

```
object FlinkApplication {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.ProcessingTime)
    env.addSource(new MySource1()) //How to MySource2 here?
      .setParallelism(1)
      .name("source1")
      .process(new MyProcess())
      .setParallelism(4)
      .addSink(new MySink())
      .setParallelism(2)
    env.execute("FlinkApplication")
  }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The API provides a lot of flexibility regarding how you can set up your processing pipelines. You can do this if you want to apply the same logic to multiple sources:

```scala
env.addSource(new MySource1())
  .process(new MyProcess())
  .addSink(new MySink())

env.addSource(new MySource2())
  .process(new MyProcess())
  .addSink(new MySink())

env.execute()
```

Or if it makes more sense to do so, you could union the two streams and then process the combined stream (or some combination of these approaches):

```scala
stream1.union(stream2)
  .process(...)
  .addSink(...)
```

It's also possible to do things the other way around if you want to fork the stream and apply different operations to each copy:

```scala
val stream: DataStream[T] = env.addSource(new MySource())

stream.process(new MyProcess1())
  .addSink(new MySink1())

stream.process(new MyProcess2())
  .addSink(new MySink2())

env.execute()
```

And wow, Flink 1.3 is more than three years old!

Comment: Thanks David @david-anderson for the perfect answer! Yes, 1.3 is too old,><